# Autocomplete feature when using Babylon.js with Vue.js in VSCode (no typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, babylonjs

I've created Vue.js 3 project, using Vite.js (no typescript).

My main.js file contains following contents:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import * as BABYLON from 'babylonjs';

const app = createApp(App);

app.config.globalProperties.$BABYLON = BABYLON;

app.mount('#app');
```

My question is: how can I force VSCode to show me available babylon.js methods when I start writing `this.$BABYLON.` ?

I've already tried adding `/// <reference path="../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts" />` on top of the file, putting `babylon.d.js` in the root of the project (but as I understand that won't work until I use typescript?) and also tried with installing `@types/babylon` package via npm.

I would like to keep the project non-typescript and enable this autocomplete feature - unfortunately I've also couldn't find any plugin for vscode that would solve this issue.